# Change a class to add it to a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this little code here:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.insert_usrdata_name').text($('.client-profile td:contains("Name:")').next().text());
        $('.insert_usrdata_email').text($('.client-profile td:contains("E-mail:")').next().text());
        $('.insert_usrdata_regdate').text($('.client-profile td:contains("Registration:")').next().text());
        $('.insert_usrdata_logindate').text($('.client-profile td:contains("Last Login Time:")').next().text());
        $('.insert_usrdata_loginIP').text($('.client-profile td:contains("Last Login From:")').next().text());
        $('.insert_webdata_domain').text($('.account-information td:contains("Domain:")').next().text());
        $('.insert_webdata_status').text($('.account-information td:contains("Status:")').next().text());
        $('.insert_diskusg_percentage').text($('.account-information td:contains("Disk Usage:")').next().text());
        $('.insert_diskusg_numbers').text($('.account-information td:contains("Disk Usage:")').next().text());
        $('.insert_bandwidthusg_numbers').text($('.account-information td:contains("Bandwidth:")').next().text());
        $('.insert_srvdata_url').text($('.account-information td:contains("Server Name:")').next().text());
        $('.insert_srvdata_srvload').text($('.account-information td:contains("Web Server Load:")').next().text());
        $('.insert_srvdata_dbload').text($('.account-information td:contains("MySQL Server Load:")').next().text());
        $('.progress.xs .diskusgbar').css('width', $('#diskUsageProgressBar .green-bar').css('width'));
        $('.progress.xs .bandusgbar').css('width', $('#BandwidthProgressBar .green-bar').css('width'));
    });
</script>
```

When I use `<span class='insert_webdata_domain'>N/A</span>` it load website URL if URL is available... But I want to make it work with a link for example `<a href="insert_webdata_domain"> Load site </a>`. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your line :

```
$('.insert_webdata_domain').text($('.account-information td:contains("Domain:")').next().text());
```

to :

```
$('.insert_webdata_domain').text('<a href="' + $('.account-information td:contains("Domain:")').next().text() + '">' + $('.account-information td:contains("Domain:")').next().text() + ' </a>');
```

**Update**

as per your comment if you want to keep span and also want to add link then:

```
$('.insert_webdata_domain')
.text($('.account-information td:contains("Domain:")').next().text())
.append('<a href="' + $('.account-information td:contains("Domain:")').next().text() + '">' + $('.account-information td:contains("Domain:")').next().text() + ' </a>');
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. I want to keep both code so that `<span class='insert_webdata_domain'>N/A</span>` still work and make `<a href="insert_webdata_domain"> Load site </a>` also work...can you help plz...

I'm using this code in a control panel like.. so when members is managing domain:- example1.com when i use the code `<span class='insert_webdata_domain'>N/A</span>` it automatically replace the text N/A to example1.com.. when user switch to another domain is change to the other domain automatically...

Comment: if your requirement fulfills then please select as an answer.. thanks